# Hosting multiple HwndHost in a WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-4.0, hwndhost

I am using an `hwndhost` element to draw DirectX content in a WPF application. When I override the `WndProc` for `HwndHost` I do get called with window messages but only by the first instance of `hwndhost` that I create.

Basically on the `WM_PAINT` message I render my DirectX scene and mark the "`handled`" parameter as true (I do check if the `hwnd` passed in the `WndProc` is my handle). Once I mark it as true, none of the other instances of `HwndHost` get the `WM_PAINT` message.

How can I get the other `HwndHost` instances to receive the `WM_PAINT` message?

Comment: Are they siblings or children of each other? If so, they might be clipped, meaning Windows won't bother sending a `WM_PAINT` message if it thinks there is nothing to draw (because the windows are completely covered).

Comment: I was doing something similar, and found no way of handling the different hwndhost elements - instead I'm using only one hwndhost, with multiple WPF elements inside. Not done yet but it might be worth looking at this option for you too.